# Embedding editable Google Sheet without CORS restrictions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to embed iframed live / editable (not published) Google Sheet on a website and be able to customise it (change some CSS, hide elements, inject new elements etc.), so in other words to handle the issue with CORS and iframe's `contentDocument` being null? I feel like using Apps Script's Web App / API could help here, particularly with authentication, but I cannot figure that out. Here's what I tried:

Responding with html fetched from plain spreadsheet link

```js
function doGet(){
  var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spread-id>/edit").getContentText();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(text);
}
```

Redirect

```js
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
    '<script>window.top.location.href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spread-id>/edit";</script>'
  ); 
}
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Don't think that's possible.

Comment: I've just run into this, maybe will shed some light https://joshuatz.com/posts/2019/google-apps-script-authorization-in-a-cross-origin-iframe

Comment: The issue simply is Google doesn't want it's live/ editable version of Google sheets to be embedded. It can detect that it's being iframed and refuse to provide any content, when framed.

Comment: honestly never had problems with live sheet embedded in an iframe, especially when spreadsheet is public.

Comment: Are you saying you can embed the editable version? Regardless, It is still impossible to get access to css , html of the embedded frame

Comment: are you able to edit? maybe I'm missing something https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fl6ybu?file=index.html

Comment: You're right. When put on the web, /edit is embeddedable. But I'm more than sure that you cannot access the source code from it's parent in any decent browser.  If you were to use a hacked browser or a cors  browser addon you may be able to do this on your browser and your browser only.

Comment: Fair enough. I think browser extension could work too but that's my last resort. I was hoping that getting content through ajax and rendering without an iframe could do the job but so far no luck. BTW. Please check an inbox, I've sent you a message via form.

Comment: Hi there @user1091733 ! To prevent a crossframe errors, could you please confirm if the [`XFrameOptionsMode`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode) is set to `ALLOWALL`?